# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Model.User[ usrId=1 ] type class Model.User to class Model.User

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

I am developing a jsf page using PrimeFaces dataTable to display a list of Users. The users are stored in objects of the class Model.User.

```
<p:dataTable id="usersDataTable" value="#{userController.users}" var="u">              
  <!-- Other columns -->
  <p:column>
     <p:commandLink oncomplete="dlg.show()" value="Show Dialog">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{u}" target="#{userController.currentUser}" />
     </p:commandLink>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The dialog will show a confirmation message, but that is not important. The point is that when I click to the commandLink the currentUser is not set and in GlassFish log I can see this error with the following stack trace:

```
WARNING: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Model.User[ usrId=1 ]
type class Model.User to class Model.User 
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Model.User[usrId=1 ] of type class Model.User to class Model.User
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:210)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Model.User[ usrId=1 ] of type class Model.User to class Model.User
at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:412)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:71)
... 35 more
```

The strange thing is that it can not convert Model.User to Model.User, it leaves me stunned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the point, your classpath is dirty. You've multiple copies of `Model.User` class in the classpath which are loaded by different class loaders.

A class which is loaded by class loader X does not [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) the very same class which is loaded by class loader Y. The classes in the average Java EE web application are managed by multiple class loaders. In a simple WAR deploy there are usually already at least four: one for JRE's internal classes (including JRE's `/lib` folder), one for servletcontainer's internal classes (including server's `/lib` folder), one for servletcontainer-managed common libraries which are shared by all webapps and finally one specific to the webapp itself (including webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder).

Imagine that you've `Model.User` class in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/classes` and another one, perhaps in flavor of a JAR file, in JRE's `/lib` or `/lib/ext` folder (some starters do that incorrectly in a careless attempt to fix compilation errors while not understanding the concept "classpath" at all), then you would face exactly this problem.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please work on your [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Package names should be all lowercase. Trying to do it different from the standards (and thus from *everyone else*) doesn't really put you in spotlight by fellow Java developers.